# BootstrapDailog is not working in Bootstrap4 with Jquery 3.3.1

Tags: bootstrap-4, android-webview, jquery-3, jquery-migrate, bootstrap-dialog

I am using BootstrapDialog with Bootstrap4 and Jquery3.3.1 when i call BootstrapDialog.confirm then it will throw an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object" in older version of chrome .I also added Jquery-migrate3.0.0 but didn't work.But BootstrapDialog is works fine with Bootstrap3 and jquery-2.2.3

Comment: please provide us your code

Comment: Actually it is worked when i updated bootstrap  to bootstrap4.1.Thanks your resposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 Dialog or Modals have been little weird. But try this solution and hope it works for you.

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```